# Finding the volume of the set of all $x \in \mathbb R^4$ satisfying $x^t A x \leq 1$ for a symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, volume

> Find the volume in $\mathbb R^4$ of the set of $x$ with $x^tAx \le 1$.  You may use the fact that the volume in $\mathbb R^4$ of the set of $x$ with $|x|^2 = x^tx\le 1$ is $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

*My work so far:*

This is part (b) of the question.  From part (a), I was given a symmetric matrix $A$, and I factored $A$ into $LL^t$, using the Cholesky factorization.  This factorization reveals easily that $$\det(A) = \det(L)\det(L^t) = (2)(2) = 4.$$

I'm guessing that I have to compute the determinant of *some* matrix to find the volume of the parallelipiped spanned by the column vectors of that matrix.  But I don't know which matrix that would be.

And, I have that the set of x that we need to compute the volume of must satisfy $$\begin{align}
x^tAx
&= x^t(LL^t)^tx \\
&= ((LL^t)x)^tx \\
&= ((LL^t)^tx)^tx \\
&= ((LL^tx)^tx \\
&= (L^tx)^t(L^tx) \\
&=||L^t(x)||^2 \\
&\le 1
\end{align}$$

Where can I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a map from $\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$; $x \mapsto L^t x$, which maps the set you are interested in to the unit sphere.  Since multiplication by a matrix $M$ causes sets to be mapped to new sets whose volume is $\det(M)$ times as large as its original volume, you deduce that the volume of your set is $\frac{\pi^2}2 \div \text{det}(L^t) = \frac{\pi^2}4$.

Comment: Hi @StephenMontgomery-Smi, can I think of det(M) as analogous to the Jacobian determinant factor in multivariable calculus?  I want to make this connection but it's not so clear:  in calculus the Jacobian is the determinant of a matrix of partial derivatives of possibly non-linear functions.  But in linear algebra, the matrix represents a linear transformation.  Is there a connection to be made here, or is there a better analogy?  Thanks, professor.

Comment: Perhaps it's better for me to not get too confused with this.  The hint given on this problem also states that this is not a calculus problem.  So, the transformation by M stretches the volume of the pre-image set by a factor of det(M).  Thanks and have a great night, professor.  And good luck with your work on the Navier-Stokes equations :-)

Comment: Nevertheless, there is a connection to be made.  This is because $|\text{det}(M)|$ is the Jacobian factor for the linear map $x \mapsto M x$.  However it is perhaps better to think of it the other way around - the reason the Jacobian factor is there is because of how linear transformations change determinants.